# Why is QWebEngineView not ready for mobie apps?

Tags: webview, qml, qt5

My apps will use some widgets to show web pages. But QTextBrowser just support HTML 4.1, and QtWebView just support QML, and QWebEngineView  just spoport Linux/Unix/MacOSX/Windows. Why does QWebEngineView not support Android and IOS?  It is the reason of Chromium donot support Android and IOS ?
Current mobie apps often use WebView to show web pages, so we can't wait for QWebEngineView. What is the official idea and plan?

Comment: read this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/51423/qtwebengine-on-android/5 and this:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html

Answer (score 1):

> It is the reason of Chromium donot support Android and IOS ?

**iOS**

Apple does not allow Chromium on iOS.

See rule #2.5.6 at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements -- *Apps that browse the web must use the appropriate WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript.*

**Android**

It is technically possible to add support for Qt WebEngine on Android, but this support does not exist at the moment.

See http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-September/013169.html for the reasons.

This is my interpretation:

- It requires a lot of work. The Qt Company's resources are being spent in other areas.
- An Android app that uses QWebEngineView will need to include the Qt WebEngine library, which is very large (~30 MB?). This is not desirable.